# Error: returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Tags: c#, return

```
    private void QuestionAnswer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtQuestion.Enabled = false;
        txtQuestion.BackColor = Color.White;
        grpMultipleChoice.Enabled = false;
        grpSingleChoice.Enabled = false;

        btnCheckAnswer.Enabled = false;
        btnNext.Enabled = false;
        btnQuit.Enabled = false;

        //force student to enter registration details
        if (txtStudentName.Text == "" && txtStudentNumber.Text == "" && txtModuleNumber.Text == "")
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter your registration details at the upper right corner");
        }

        //declare a list
        lstNumbers = new ArrayList();

        //create a random number generator
        Random rndNumber = new Random();

        //generate 70 random numbers
        //int number = (int)(rndNumber.NextDouble() * 69) + 1;

        //lstNumbers.Add(number);
        ///use this counter to loop whenever a number is generated
        int count = 0;
        int maximumNumber = 69;

        ///disable answer button 
        btnCheckAnswer.Enabled = false;
        do
        {

            int number = (int)(rndNumber.NextDouble() * maximumNumber) + 1;
            lstNumbers.Add(number);
            if (!lstNumbers.Contains(number))
            {
                lstNumbers.Add(number);
            }
            count++;

        } while (count <= 15 * 70);//
        btnCheckAnswer_Click(sender, e);
        return lstNumbers;//returns once list is built
     }
```

Explanation:
I have created  an arraylist that allows me generate randomly between 1-70 but noticed 
my numbers where somewhat repeating. In a bid to prevent this, i noticed i was getting an
error message below:

Error   1 Since 'wwTestAppV1.GenKnow.QuestionAnswer_Load(object, System.EventArgs)' **returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression**

i have tried everything i can to resolve this.the program runs well when i remove this 
statement but shows duplicate values. Could you please help?

Comment: you mean: return lstNumbers? i have tried that before stll show the squiggle on return.

Comment: Unless you are programming in Visual Studio 2003 and C# 1, you should not be using an ArrayList. Use List<T> from System.Collections.Generic

Comment: I would like to add that    private void QuestionAnswer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) is the method under which it falls. I have even tried changing void to string so i could return with a To String() but it still doesn't work

Comment: Its on Visual studio 2012 @ Anthony

Comment: It's been stated already that by using 'void' you are in essence saying that your function will return nothing. You need to specify the exact type of the object you intend to return. (Sorry my previous comment was c++ ... so I deleted it).

Answer (score 10):

Your method signature is:

```
private void QuestionAnswer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The return type `void` means you can't/aren't planning to return anything. However, at the bottom, you have:

```
return lstNumbers;//returns once list is built
```

You're returning something! The compiler is complaining that you told it conflicting instructions. Either change the return type to `ArrayList` or do not return anything.

That being said, there are several improvements that could be made to the code to make it more readable, which will help you decipher problems, too. Consider submitting your code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Right.  So change private void to private yourobject or private T if you want to keep the object returned undefined.

Comment: He sounds like he's very new to programming. I wouldn't suggest that he start writing generic methods just yet.

Comment: when i change method to private string QuestionAnswer_load(...., iget error..Error 1 'string wwTestAppV1.GenKnow.QuestionAnswer_Load(object, System.EventArgs)' has the wrong return type

Comment: @annoying_squid; my object is lstNumbers right? its suppose to represent the list

Comment: 1stNumbers is an instance of your type ArrayList.  Try private ArrayList QuestionAnswer_Load .. instead.  You specify the type not the name of the instance.  The compiler won't understand specific names.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.ArrayList wwTestAppV1.GenKnow.QuestionAnswer_Load(object, System.EventArgs)' has the wrong return type

Comment: I think you should read up on some general intro to programming tutorials.