# Returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, return

I want to send an email in C # ASP.NET, the problem is that I mark this error "returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression". In both "return" marks the same error, what is this?

```
 try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com", "jhon", Encoding.UTF8);
             mail.Subject = "test email";
            mail.Body = "test email c#";
            mail.To.Add("michael@hotmail.com");
            SmtpServer.Port = 587; 
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What is the return type of your method where you using this code?

Comment: does the method return a boolean?

Comment: Does you method signature has `void` return type ?

Comment: The most relevant code is missing.

Comment: Dude, I hope you sharing fake credentials!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843501/error-returns-void-a-return-keyword-must-not-be-followed-by-an-object-expressi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message means that your method's return type is `void`, while your code implies that your method should be returning `true` for successfully sent e-mails, or `false` to indicate failures.

Changing method's return type to `bool` should fix this problem. However, a better approach is to keep the method `void`, and throw a custom exception indicating an unsuccessful attempt to send an e-mail:

```
public class SendMailException : Exception {
    public SendMailException(Exception cause) : base(cause) {
    }
}
...
try {
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    // return true is removed
} catch (Exception cause) {
    throw new SendMailException(cause);
    // return false is removed
}
```

Comment: Also, if at any point the intention is just to break out of code if a condition occurs, but NOT throw an error, just use `return;` when the method type is `void`.

Answer (score 2):

i think that your function is defined as void, and you're returning a boolean, try changing the return value expected to bool like so:

```
bool myFunction(){
```

instead of

```
void myFunction(){
```